# create custom grid control wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, grid

hi i want load some data from database but i dont want to use default wpf grid control i want create a tiny control just like this pic:
[control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvm5E.jpg)

And in some way, like these, I display the information in control:

```
foreach (var element in data)
{
    myControl.newitem.Title = element.Title;
 myControl.newitem.Content = element.Content;
 myControl.newitem.Image = element.Image;
 myControl.newitem.Date = element.Date ;
}
```

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Does it really have to work exactly that way or are you just interested in the end result.  You could bind data for the heading and itemssource for the items and template the data to produce that effect.

Comment: @Clemens tnx Your answer has solved my problem Now I am studying and testing

Answer (score 1):

I would use the standard WPF ItemsControl for this.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding data}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            ....
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```